# Send a custom ble uuid

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I create a cross-platform app using flutter.

the user logged in and the user if send it to home page when the button send clicked a custom ble signal advertised included the user id

Login page

```
    UserId = responseData['userId'];

    print('User ID: $userID');
    print(userID.runtimeType);

    print('------------------------');

    saveUserData(userEmail,passwordCrypted,UserId);
    print('id:  $userID');
```

Home

```
  String hexString = myInt.toRadixString(16); // Pad to 8 characters
  String uuid = '$hexString-2900-441A-802F-9C398FC199D2';

  bool isValid = isValidUUID(uuid);

  if (isValid) 
  {
    try 
    {
      beaconBroadcast
          .setUUID(uuid)
          .setMajorId(1)
          .setMinorId(100)
          .start();

      print('BLE Signal Sent Successfully');
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
      print('Error Broadcasting BLE Signal: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which package is used for BLE?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question?